# On startup - remove disks or other media

Tags: windows-7, boot

I have windows 7 installed on my laptop.
I was attempting to resize some partitions in the disk manager. I made some changes (extended my C:\ into some unalocated space) then restarted.
It now displays

> Remove disks or other media Press any
>   key to restart

Is there any way of recovering from this? or has the system had it?

Comment: there's always a way of recovering IF you created a drive image (as it is always recommended BEFORE fiddling with partitions).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may have corrupted the MBR. First I'd recommend backing up your data. Then, try booting from a Windows installer CD and entering **R** to get in the recovery console. Once in, give these commands a go in this order:

```
bootrec /RebuildBCD
bootrec /FixBoot
bootrec /FixMBR
```

Comment: backing up data might be tricky - i use bitlocker.
No real biggy... it's mostly backed up any way... just a bit annoying!

Is it possible the H/D could of failed? it was "clunking" last week

Comment: Very possible. Give some of the diagnostic tools on ultimate boot cd a try to confirm: http://ultimatebootcd.com or even try writing to it with a Linux LiveCD.